# How to pair Galaxy J5 with Samsung gear S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-gear, samsung-galaxy-j5

I tried many times to install Samsung gear manager in my device(galaxy J5), but after a successful install what should I do?

When I use the app in my phone it gives me this error: `check if your phone is compatible or...`

My phone Bluetooth and my gear Bluetooth both are on.

Please help me how can I pair these two products of Samsung!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[According to GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_gear_smartwatches_work_with_these_20_devices-news-8301.php), the Gear S is only compatible with some Samsung phones, not including the Galaxy J5. That page was from a few years ago, but [the O2 product page for the Gear S](https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/wearables/samsung/gear-s/) agrees.

As Samsung has replaced the Gear S with the Gear S 2, whose chief selling point is that it additionally supports some non-Samsung phones, they're unlikely to revisit the Gear S software to make it compatible with more phones.

[This linked question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/55411/12442) about an unsupported way of getting the original Galaxy Gear to pair with non-Samsung phones may also be relevant to you.